# drawRect in transformed UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have an view inside a `UIScrollView`. On that view I set a scale transform, so it compensates for the zooming and stays the same size.

While the transform seems to work on all subviews, filling the `bounds` in the view's own `drawRect` seems to fill the whole frame, as if there was no scale transform applied.

Why can this be?

Comment: Have you tested "clipsToBounds = YES;" on your UIView?

Comment: Well, I can't clip to bounds because one subview goes beyound the bounds. Even if I could, the bounds size would still be too large, compared to what I expect when a scale transform is applied.

Comment: Does the drawing with and without transform work as you expect when the view is not contained by the scroll view?  Trying that might be a good way to simplify the problem.

Comment: Ahh, so it's a problem related to zooming/scrolling the view with multiple subviews.. Hmm, then it gets very interesting since it has something with the context to do probably :) Can't help you there though. Not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was aware that I could not use the `frame` property in a transformed view, but actually setting it yourself on a transformed view is also a no-no.

> if the transform property contains a non-identity transform,
>   the value of the frame property is undefined and should **not be modified**

I removed all code that uses `self.frame` in any way and used `self.center` instead. Now everything displays correctly.